# Scroll back to a DIV's position from JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a series of expandable content DIVs that are collapsed initially and expands upon clicking on another DIV with a heading text. See the code sample below.

```
<div id="post">
   <div class="heading" onclick="opendiv()">...Heading...</div>
   <div class="body">.....Lengthy content.....</div>
</div>
....
....
```

'body' class initially hides the 'body' DIV having a 'lengthy content'. 
When clicked on the 'heading' DIV, 'body' DIV expands making the web page scrollable.
Remember that there are 5 or more such expandable DIV sets above and below this set. 
When the 'body' section is clicked, the page must scroll back to its 'heading' DIV location.

Here is the js script I use to expand and collapse above DIVs. But this scrolling back to a given DIV does not work.

```
function opendiv() {
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("div#post div.heading").offset().top});

    if ($("div#post div.body").css("display") == "block") {
        $("div#post div.body").hide();
     } else {
        $("div#post div.body").show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Since ids are uniq, no need to put the tag name in front of the selector .. `$("#post div.heading")`

Comment: Scrolling to div works fine with this code (of course after clicking `.header`, not `.body` as you are saying, it's because of wrong implementation. Look at answer below).

Comment: if you're using jQM, use `$.mobile.silentScrol()`.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't add any event listeners to the `.body` div

```
<div class="body" onclick="gotoHead()">.....Lengthy content.....</div>
```

then your `gotoHead()` function might look like this

```
function gotoHead() {
    document.body.scrollTop = $('#post .heading').offset().top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description there are a few issues with the way you coded the script. One is that there is no click event for the .body div. The second is that you are coding your javascript click events directly in to the HTML. Typically unless it must be done this way it is better to declare your events in your JavaScript, which is generally easier to go back and edit for new functionality.

Here is a refresh of what you did:

```
$('.heading').click(function(e){
    // hide or show the corresponding .body div
    $(this).parent().children('div.body').toggle();
});

$('.body').click(function(e){
    // scroll to the corresponding .heading div
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).parent().children('div.heading').offset().top
    }); 
});
```

You can also see this in action here:
http://jsfiddle.net/joncox/pmeEs/